# How can I check if a user is currently logged in and playing a facebook app game

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-apps

I'm making a facebook app game and I was wondering how can I check if a particular user is currently logged in and playing the game.

e.g.
When I open my friends list in a game, I can see if they are offline or online

or when I send a private message to someone in a game. If they are offline, the chat will prompt you that the particular user is currently offline etc.

Btw I'm writing in php and js and for DB i'm using mysql.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can check if friends are online using online_presence

SELECT uid FROM user WHERE   online_presence IN ('active', 'idle')   AND uid IN (     SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()  )

You will need to obtain the friends_online_presence permission. This will tell you which friends are logged into Facebook, not logged into your game. To determine who is logged into your game, you'll have to implement something inside your application code to track which users are currently online (this shouldn't be dependent on anything to do with Facebook, as the code will be running on your server, and user sessions will be managed by your code)

Hope this is helpful.